# Magento2 reference a block and call method from it in layout.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I have a file `Vendor_Module/view/rontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`
in my custom module.

The content of the file is as fallows:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock" name="my_custom_block" template="custom_template.phtml">
        <action method="customMethod">
            <argument><--call public method method from parent block 'product.info'--></argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I want to define a method to my custom block inside the **catalog_product_view.xml** file of my module and pass argument to that method that is the result which is returned by calling of a public method from the reference block. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just extend referenceBlock class in Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock and do the "magic" there? :)

Comment: yeah, i am wondering if this can work.  It would be awesome :D